# UIView remove itself from UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

Following Scenario:

I have a = UIViewController A that contains a UIScrollView

I have a second UIViewController "B" (amongst other things it contains a button)
and add it to the ScrollView of A

myView *mView = [[myView alloc] init];
[myScrollView addSubview:mView.view];

Is there a way that once the button is pressed that it(view) removes itself from the scrollview?

I thought in the direction of setting the delegate of mView to "A" ?! But not sure how that should work in detail....

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller, you can call:

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reference to view you can do the following:

```
[view removeFromSuperview];
```

If you don't have a reference, please post more code and I can modify my answer for you.